# How to get line breaks in e-mail sent using Python's smtplib?

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, smtplib

I have written a script that writes a message to a text file and also sends it as an email. 
Everything goes well, except the email finally appears to be all in one line.

I add line breaks by `\n` and it works for the text file but not for the email. 
Do you know what could be the possible reason?

---

Here's my code:

```
import smtplib, sys
import traceback
def send_error(sender, recipient, headers, body):

    SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    SMTP_PORT = 587
    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo
    session.login(sender, 'my password')
    send_it = session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" +  body)
    session.quit()
    return send_it


SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = 587
sender = 'sender_id@gmail.com'
recipient = 'recipient_id@yahoo.com'
subject = 'report'
body = "Dear Student, \n Please send your report\n Thank you for your attention"
open('student.txt', 'w').write(body) 

headers = ["From: " + sender,
               "Subject: " + subject,
               "To: " + recipient,
               "MIME-Version: 1.0",
               "Content-Type: text/html"]
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)
send_error(sender, recipient, headers, body)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have your message body declared to have HTML content (`"Content-Type: text/html"`). The HTML code for line break is [`<br>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp). You should either change your content type to `text/plain` or use the HTML markup for line breaks instead of plain `\n` as the latter gets ignored when rendering a HTML document.

---

As a side note, also have a look at the [email package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html). There are some classes that can simplify the definition of E-Mail messages for you ([with examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)).

For example you could try (untested):

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# define content
recipients = ["recipient_id@yahoo.com"]
sender = "sender_id@gmail.com"
subject = "report reminder"
body = """
Dear Student,
Please send your report
Thank you for your attention
"""

# make up message
msg = MIMEText(body)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

# sending
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.starttls()
session.login(sender, 'my password')
send_it = session.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
session.quit()
```

Answer (score 45):

Unfortunately for us all, not every type of program or application uses the same standardization that python does.

Looking at your question i notice your header is: `"Content-Type: text/html"`

Which means you need to use HTML style tags for your new-lines, these are called line-breaks. `<br>`

Your text should be:

```
"Dear Student, <br> Please send your report<br> Thank you for your attention"
```

If you would rather use character type new-lines, you must change the header to read: `"Content-Type: text/plain"`

You would still have to change the new-line character from a single `\n` to the double `\r\n` which is used in email.

Your text would be:

```
"Dear Student, \r\n Please send your report\r\n Thank you for your attention"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. `\r\n` doesn't work for me but the `<br>` does.

Comment: `<p/>` also works.

Answer (score 7):

In my case `'\r\n'` didn't work, but `'\r\r\n'` did. So my code was:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
body = 'Dear Student,\r\r\nPlease send your report\r\r\nThank you for your attention'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
```

The message is written in multiple lines and is displayed correctly in Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

I've also run into this as well.  I had found a little bit of white space at the end of the line was enough for my SMTP service to recognize the new line

```py
body = 'value of variable x = ' + myVarX + "   \r\n"  \
       + 'value of variable y = ' + myVarY
```

I believe this to be more of a SMTP issue, rather than a Python issue, which may explain the range in solutions in this thread

Comment: 3 spaces worked for me, thanks. 2 spaces not enough, I'd love an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Setting the content-type header to `Content-Type: text/plain` (with `\r\n` at the end) allowed me to send multi-line plain-text emails.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook will remove line feeds from plain text it believes are extras.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287816

You can try below update to make the lines look like bullets.  That worked for me.

```
body = "Dear Student, \n- Please send your report\n- Thank you for your attention"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and this thread was helpful in determining why it was happening in the first place. I was at a lost, because I knew my code was correct. I tried a few things, but what worked for me was adding a \t\n for each line in the body.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
lines = ['line1', 'line2', 'line3']
body = '\t\n'.join(lines)
msg = MIMEText(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the version of python.
for version 3.11.1,
you should use '\r\n' for line break

reference the official doc [https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#:~:text=using%20BytesGenerator%20with-,%5Cr%5Cn%20as%20the%20linesep,-%2C%20and%20calls%20sendmail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#:%7E:text=using%20BytesGenerator%20with-,%5Cr%5Cn%20as%20the%20linesep,-%2C%20and%20calls%20sendmail)

Answer (score 0):

I got success while running a smtp mail that get subject and content via parameter
(using python 3.11.3 windows 10)

```
import sys
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage


if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg["Subject"] = sys.argv[1]
    # this does the magick replacing \n to \r\n
    # without this the mail will show \n als text
    msg.set_content(sys.argv[2].replace("\\n",'\r\n')) 
    msg["From"] = "-PUT-SEND-FROM-HERE-"
    msg["To"] = "-PUT-SEND-TO-HERE-"
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP("-PUT-SMTP-SERVER-HERE", 587)
    smtpObj.ehlo()
    smtpObj.starttls()
    smtpObj.login("-PUT-LOGINMANE-HERE-", "-PUT-PASSWORD-HERE")
    smtpObj.send_message(msg)
    smtpObj.quit()
else:
    # Errormesssage
    print("Please add Subject and Content as parameter")
```