# How do you insert a new line into a message using EmailMessage (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm using EmailMessage to send emails via Amazon SES in Django. I am currently having trouble inserting new lines in the message. "\n" does not seem to work

How do I go about doing this?

As an example, this is what I've tried:

```
subject= "Test email with newline" 
message = "%s %s is testing an email with a newline.  \nCheck out this link too: http://www.example.com" % (user.first_name, user.last_name)
from_string = "<support@example.com>"
email_message = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_string, [user.email])
email_message.send()
```

When I send this email I get:

```
 Michael Smith is testing an email with a newline. Check out this link too: 
 http://www.example.com
```

However, I expected the email to be formatted like this:

```
Michael Smith is testing an email with a newline. 
Check out this link too: http://www.example.com
```

Comment: This is just a guess but have you tried making this a raw string? `message = r"%s %s is testing an email with a newline.  \nCheck out this link too: http://www.example.com" % (user.first_name, user.last_name)`

Comment: Try also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139165/how-to-get-line-breaks-in-e-mail-sent-using-pythons-smtplib)

Comment: Might also take two newlines, because HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**attach_alternative()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) and provide html - in your case `<p>` or `<br>` will do the trick.

or

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

subject= "Test email with newline"
html_context = "%s %s is testing an email with a newline.  <br>Check out this link too: http://www.example.com" % (user.first_name, user.last_name)
from_string = "<support@example.com>"
msg = EmailMessage(subject,
                   html_context,
                   from_string,
                   [user.email])
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

The better use is case it try sending html message where you can send email as html. There you can format your msg like whatever you want