# python sending email - line breaks removed by Outlook

Tags: python, email, outlook

I am sending some emails from Python using *smtplib* *MIMEtext*; and have the often noted problem that Outlook will "sometimes" remove what it considers "extra line breaks".

It is odd, because I print several headers and they all break find, but the text fields in a table are all smooshed - unless the recipient manually clicks Outlook's "restore line breaks".

Because some come through alright, I wonder what is Outlook's criteria for "extra", and thus how to avoid it?

Do I need to format the message as HTML?

Comment: do you use `\n` or `\r\n` as line breaks?

Comment: Tried both - no difference.

Comment: Add 3 spaces before \r\n, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139165/how-to-get-line-breaks-in-e-mail-sent-using-pythons-smtplib

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to fix this.  Outlook does it no matter how many line breaks you put in there in my experience.  You might be able to trick it by adding spaces on each line, or non-breaksping space characters.  It's a dumb feature of outlook....

Comment: Thanks. I reformatted the output lines, with some additional spaces (for appearance), and it went away. Argh. There must be some solution - since most all Outlook emails do display correctly - perhaps they are HTML?

Comment: Thanks Artagel.  I also found that some characters (spaces) are narrower than others in the lines.  I had to do some fiddling to get my lines looking reasonable...