# How to combine two string variables into one multiline variable?

Tags: python, string, mime, smtplib

I want to use python to send an email with two rows(lines) of text like this

```
a    b    c    d
e    f    g    h
```

I tried to use `xxx.attach()` but I found that the second row is replaced the first one.

```
part1 = MIMEText(text1, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(text2, 'plain')
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
```

So, I tried to define each line as a string variable and then combine it together. Finally, I attach only one variable.

```
A="a   b   c   d"
B="e   f   g   h"
```

How to combine A and B to get the result as above?

PS. I am using Python3.6 on Windows10

Comment: Does `list(msg.walk())` show the two attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the os module for this

```
import os
A = "a   b   c   d"
B = "e   f   g   h"
temp = os.linesep.join([A,B])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Windows, which has a different line separation character than Linux/Unix, you can use join + the os's native line separator.

```
import os
A = "a   b   c   d"
B = "e   f   g   h"
C = os.linesep.join([A,B])
```

MIMEText could be different, especially if you're using any encoding other than text/plain. [Try this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139165/how-to-get-line-breaks-in-e-mail-sent-using-pythons-smtplib) if your email message is HTML rather than plain text.